# Nested block and getChildHtml()

Tags: magento-1.9

I have some trouble when i get data with function getChildHtml() . 
Here is my layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <hello_index_index>
          <reference name="content">
               <block type="hello/hello" name="title" template="hello/title.phtml">
                      <block type="hello/hello" name="title1" template="hello/title1.phtml">
                            <block type="hello/hello" name="title2" template="hello/title2.phtml"/>
                      </block>
               </block>
          </reference>
    </hello_index_index>
</layout>
```

when i try print data in file title2.phtml to the screen with code is

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('title2');
```

**OR**

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('title1');
```

In the first way is no data displayed on the screen . 
In the second way have data displayed on the screen but only data in file title1.phtml . 
So how to display the data in file title2.phtml 
Thank everybody .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `title2` is a child block of `title1`, in the template for `title1` you should have this line.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('title2')?>
```

or simply

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml()?>
```

This second call will list all the child blocks.

Then, in `title.phtml` use

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('title1')?>
```

or simply

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml()?>
```

Comment: Thank for your help . It useful for me :)